# Do Cote d'Ivoire eVisas have a specific entry date?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, e-visas, africa

I successfully obtained an eVisa for Ivory Coast two months ago.
Now my flight was rescheduled to an earlier date. 
Can I still enter the country or is there a date of entry specified on the eVisa? i.e. am I going to have to wait in the airport until the originally specified date of arrival?

(The period of stay is no problem and also the date of leave is the same as when I requested the Visa)

Comment: Independent to the answer: you should check with airlines. "wait in the airport" is not always possible (many airport close at night, and airlines may not board you if you do no have a valid visa at arrival).

Comment: What is the ‘pre-enrollment approval’ date on your e-visa confirmation? https://snedai.com/e-visa/ says pre-approval is valid for 3 months from the approval date

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.